# Angular Rxjs Manage Nested Subscriptions

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

Hi I've a function which has nested subscriptions.

```
  public loadUser(): Observable<string> {
    return this.getUser().subscribe(
      (userResponse: any) => {
        if (userResponse) {
          this.userId = userResponse.toLowerCase();
          this.getAppSupportUsersList();
          this.getUserEntitlements().subscribe((response: any) => {
            localStorage.setItem('UserEntitlements', JSON.stringify(response));
            this.processUIEntitlements(response);
            this.getUserDetails(this.userId).subscribe((userDetails) => {
              this.userInfo = userDetails;
              this.setUserName();
            });
          });
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

I'm not sure how can we avoid nesting of subscriptions. Is there a better way to rewrite the nested subscriptions using `switchMap()` or `mergeMap()`?

Comment: Here you have a nice and clean answer on how to restructure your nested subscriptions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53584118/angular-rxjs-best-practices-to-subscribe-multiple-http-requests-depending-from-p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be re-written with a rxjs [switchMap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap) or a [map](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map), depending on how you want to handle multiple requests.

If only the latest counts, which seems to be the most indicated since you are writing to the local storage, go with the `switchMap` approach.

```
public loadUser(): Observable<string> {
  return this.getUser().pipe(
    filter(val => !!val),
    switchMap(userResponse => {
      this.userId = userResponse.toLowerCase();
      this.getAppSupportUsersList();
      return this.getUserEntitlements();
    }),
    switchMap(response => {
      localStorage.setItem('UserEntitlements', JSON.stringify(response));
      this.processUIEntitlements(response);
      return this.getUserDetails(this.userId);
    }),
    .map(userDetails => {
      this.userInfo = userDetails;
      this.setUserName();
      return JSON.stringify(userDetails);
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on the second line return... `Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<string>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more.ts(2740)` How to get rid of this? Seems like it returns an subscription and not an observable

Comment: The error is because we are returning an Observable string in the method declaration, `public loadUser(): Observable<string>` but in reality, we return an Subscription.

If you don't need to return an observable, you can simply update the method declaration to `public loadUser(): void`. If you need to return an `observable<string>` then what is the string property that should be returned? It is not clear on the question.

Comment: `getUser()` is just making an HTTP get API call and returns the single string value and return like `'stackoverflow'`

Comment: Updated to return the value of `JSON.stringify(userDetails)`. Keep in mind that this way, you need to subscribe to this method somewhere to trigger the request.

Answer (score 1):

We can use [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap), since we just want to chain subscriptions, switch to another after the previous is done.

```
  public loadUser(): Observable<string> {
    return this.getUser().pipe(
      switchMap((userResponse: any) => {
        if (userResponse) {
          this.userId = userResponse.toLowerCase();
          this.getAppSupportUsersList();
          return this.getUserEntitlements().pipe(
            switchMap((response: any) => {
              localStorage.setItem('UserEntitlements', JSON.stringify(response));
              this.processUIEntitlements(response);
              return this.getUserDetails(this.userId).pipe(
                tap((userDetails) => {
                  this.userInfo = userDetails;
                  this.setUserName();
                })
              )
            })
          );
        }
        return of(null);
      })
    );
  }

  callingFunction() {
      this.loadUser().subscribe({
        next: (next) => {
          console.error(next);
        },
        error: (error) => {
          console.error(error);
        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: If the subscription is a http request, this doesn't make sense.
HTTP request made with the angular client auto unsubscribe, so this unnecessary overload.

Comment: @NarenMurali What is the difference between mine and your code. Yours too is nesting subscription only right

Comment: @Urvashi But there is no multiple subscribe, do you want me to simplify it further?

Comment: @IDK4real "If the subscription is a http request, this doesn't make sense. HTTP request made with the angular client auto unsubscribe, so this unnecessary overload" it's absolutely not an overload. The subscription does not auto unsubscribe at all, it completes as soon as the server responds, which is really different. For example, if you create a small expressjs server with an endpoint and you never resolve, hence keeping an HTTP call open forever, if the component or service from which you'd call that endpoint would keep that observable open.

Comment: Reference in [Docs](https://angular.io/guide/http-request-data-from-server)

Comment: To quote the angular docs linekd by @NareMurali:
You don't have to unsubscribe from HttpClient observables because they unsubscribe automatically after the server request responds or times out. Most developers choose not to unsubscribe.
Also the stackoverflow like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042929/is-it-necessary-to-unsubscribe-from-observables-created-by-http-methods and other aggree that there is no need to manually unsubscribe. At most, it could use a takeUntilDestroyed to ensure all requests are closed in case the view is destroyed which, again, is mentioned in the docs