# rxjs - Tap vs subscribe

Tags: rxjs

In many articles I find that `tap` operator is a good way to perform side effects. My question is about a difference between performing side effects using subscribe and tap. Here are examples which are doing actually the same:

```
        this.store$
           .pipe(tap(x => {
               this.store = x;
           }));

        this.store$
           .subscribe(x => {
              this.store = x;
           });
```

Is there any difference in the performance or is there any reason to use one of these approaches?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tap() vs subscribe() to set a class property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49184754/tap-vs-subscribe-to-set-a-class-property)

Answer (score 1):

In Angular context.
You may have a component say MyComponent. There is a service as well for this component MyService. This service is responsible for some complex operation in MyComponent. Now you will make the subscription in the MyComponent as

```
$myObs.subscribe((val) => //do something );
```

But same data may be required in your service as well, so you define it in service as

```
$myObs.pipe(tap((val) => // do something with data in service));
```

Subscription will be done in component but using tap you can assign data member variable in your service as well.